# How can I generate a random-float number that less than or equal to a number in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I should generate a floating number between 0 and 100 (**upper limit must be included**). *random-float* generates strictly less than 100. What I would like to learn how this code could be changed to the desired form. Is there any more creative way than​ simply adding  0.00000000000001 on the generated number?

Comment: There is an answer for this in [the NetLogo FAQ](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#the-documentation-says-that-random-float-1-might-return-0-but-will-never-return-1-what-if-i-want-1-to-be-included).  The short answer is it probably won't matter if the upper limit is included, since when using floats you'll never really see the upper limit randomly generated.  There are some workarounds in that answer, too, though.

Comment: just generate a random number to 101.1 and then test it and generate a new one if it's too large

Comment: @Jasper thank you so much. that is exactly what i was looking for ‍♂️

Comment: @JenB thanks. i should generate 1500 numbers. @Jasper’s advice works for my solution ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(random 100001 / 1000)* works for me. The output both includes 100 and 0 (the upper and the lower limit). Thanks.

Comment: no it doesn't. OP is asking for floating point. Dividing any number X by any other number Y is never going to get you 0 as a result unless X is already 0. And 100000.99 (for example) divided by 1000 is larger than the upper limit required.

Comment: hi @JenB, to seeing "0" is possible if you run random 100001 and the highest number could be 100000. when we divide all numbers to 1000, we will get numbers between 0 and 100 that have 3 digits after comma. the precision is enough for my work.

Answer (score 0):

does this work:

```
let i random-float 100
let j 100 - i
```

if `i = 0` then `j = 100`

but j will never be 0.

that said, the probability of getting a float exactly equal to a given number is basically 0. Floats are so exact that there's a few million possible values between 0 and 100. See [this article](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/) for instance.

If you're building a model where this distinction does matter, you probably want something beside netlogo :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Hugh! What if I want to generate 50 different random numbers between 0 and 100, how possible are numbers distributed uniformly? I will be grateful if you have any idea about that 

Comment: thanks, you can mark it as answered if the solution works. Really depends on the context for the 50 random numbers, you could save them as a list but you probably want them to set a turtle or patch variable (?) so you'd probably do it one at a time inside an `ask turtles/patches`. work on it for a while and open a new Q if you have to